# Access VBA - Dlookup for checking duplicates (composite unique key)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a join table, that consist FK from 2 tables. These two fields are set for composite unique key index, and I need to check for duplicates with DlookUp, If possible. Here is what I tried:

```
Nz(DLookup("PK_JoinTable", "JoinTable", "FK_FirstTable = " & Me.FK_FirstTable & "AND FK_SecondTable= " & Me.FK_SecondTable & _
                    " AND PK_JoinTable <> " & Nz(Me.PK_JoinTable, 0)), 0)
```

Is possible to use DLookUp for this case ?

EDIT: Here is my Table design...

```
JoinTable

PK_JoinTable
FK_FirstTable
FK_SecondTable
```

These foreign key table fields have unique index. I have a form where I enter data that joins both tables via Combobox. And I need to prevent duplicates entries. Both in Before_Update event, and Click event of "Save" button. This is my whole code for now (click_event of button):

```
Dim Duplicates As Long

Duplicates = Nz(DLookup("PK_JoinTable", "JoinTable", "FK_FirstTable = " & Me.FK_FirstTable & "AND FK_SecondTable= " & Me.FK_SecondTable & _
                        " AND PK_JoinTable <> " & Nz(Me.PK_JoinTable, 0)), 0)

 If Duplicates > 0 Then

           Cancel = True
      MsgBox "Duplicate entry. This record will not be saved !, vbCritical
      DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
      Exit Sub

      Else
           ' nothing
      End If
```

Comment: It is possible but that's not a good approach according to me. Dlookup returns only one value and can only query one table. You would better to work with pure SQL and a recordset, or to create a Query. If you need help with this, edit your question and add your tableS structure and a data sample

Comment: @ThomasG,see my edited question.

Comment: That's a bit clearer but there's obviously something wrong: in your `Dlookup`, you work on a column named `PK_JoinTable` and I don't see this column described in your table struct. So, still  confusing.

Comment: Sorry, typing mistake. see now.

Comment: ok that's better. And if I understand correctly, the `PK_JoinTable` is always the concatenation of `FK_FirstTable` + `FK_SecondTable`  ? Or its totally unrelated ?

Comment: I don't quite understand, but I think It's unrelated.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, but in my eyes it's not very good practice to relay on code for DB integrity, better to relay on DB tools. I would look into creating a [multicolumn unique index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127698/can-we-create-multicolumn-unique-indexes-on-ms-access-databases). Access has them too...

Comment: I have allready created a multicolumn index, BUT I WANT TO AVOID Access window, tha'ts why I want to check for duplicates myself. Access window keep poping up, that's main problem.

Comment: Yup, saw that in later comment. Sorry.. What does Access window say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your explanations in comments, yes it is possible to do this with a `Dlookup`, but you had a small mistake in yours,  you missed a space before `AND FK_SecondTable` :

```
Nz(DLookup("PK_JoinTable", "JoinTable", "FK_FirstTable = " & Me.FK_FirstTable & " AND FK_SecondTable= " & Me.FK_SecondTable & _
                    " AND PK_JoinTable <> " & Nz(Me.PK_JoinTable, 0)), 0)
```

You can also try this approach which achieve the same thing as your `Dlookup`, but is clearer IMO, offers more possibilities if your query goes more complex, and is easier to debug and tweak.

```
Dim RST As Recordset
Dim strSQL as string

strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT(Attribute) FROM Table_Setting WHERE Attribute NOT IN (SELECT Attribute FROM Table_Setting WHERE BookType='" & strBookType & "')"

Set RST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
If  Not RST.BOF Then

    ' Looks like we have duplicates

  RST.Close
  Set RS = Nothing

  Cancel = True
  MsgBox "Duplicate entry. This record will not be saved !", vbCritical
  DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
  Exit Sub          

End If
```

Comment: You were right, what a stupid mistake. Ok I'll test this one too, but my code also works. A BIG THANKS Thomas !!!

Answer (score 1):

To debug your DLookup call, construct the WHERE part in a separate string and `Debug.Print` it (Ctrl+G opens the Immediate window).

```
strSql = "FK_FirstTable = " & Me.FK_FirstTable & _
         "AND FK_SecondTable= " & Me.FK_SecondTable & _
         " AND PK_JoinTable <> " & Nz(Me.PK_JoinTable, 0)
Debug.Print strSql
Duplicates = Nz(DLookup("PK_JoinTable", "JoinTable", strSql), 0)
```

You'll notice that you are missing a space between `Me.FK_FirstTable` and `AND`.

Comment: Nice one Andre, I allready solved my problem, but this is nice to know. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You should just point these tables together in a query and perform a dlookup on the query if needed. If you specifically need the composite key you can concatenate the needed columns under an alias column.

All in all there's probably a much easier way to accomplish your overall goal but your short on detail... so I just answered with what 
was provided.

With your updated question... the simplistic way to avoid duplicates is to create a unique index based off the three columns.

Comment: see my edited question. I hope you'll understand now.

Comment: Avoiding duplicates is allready active, from my code you see that I'm trying to avoid Access built-in msgbox. So I don't see why this should help me, Access window will still pop-up. Or  did you mean something else ?

Answer (score 0):

Debugging will be quite complicated when database is big with Dlookup, I suggest using where function is very important as well aa try to use foreign key as much as to remove complexities in ur database. If it is big then only.