# How can I check existing columns in a table before adding a record?

Tags: vba, ms-access, duplicates

I have a table called Visitor. It can accept duplicate values. I mean the same visitor can come to the shop many times but only one time per day.

| Visitor_Name | Purchase Price | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 200.00 USD | 15/12/2020 |
| Bob | 150.00 USD | 15/12/2020 |
| Marshall | 170.00 USD | 16/12/2020 |

I need to add a check.
If I try to add John with existing date (15/12/2020) then prevent the record insertion with a popup message "Visitor already visited the shop in that particular day".

This is the code I'm currently using.

```vb
Private Sub add()
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Visitor([Visitor_Name], [Purchase Price], [Date] VALUES ([Text1].Value, [Text2].Value, [Text3].Value)"
End Sub
```

Before adding a record I need to check the Visitor_Name value and Date value with all existing values related to that particular visitor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127698/can-we-create-multicolumn-unique-indexes-on-ms-access-databases

Comment: I think above link is not related to my situation. My table can accept duplicate values.

Comment: A unique index on Visitor name and Date would prevent the types of entries you're asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by using [DCount](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dcount-function-f6b5d78b-ad0b-4e42-be7a-11a64acbf3d3) to count how many entries in the table contain that `Visitor_Name` and `Date`, exiting early if it is not 0:

```vb
Private Sub add()
   If(DCount("Visitor_Name", "Visitor", "Visitor_Name=""" & [Text1].Value & """ AND [Date]=#" & [Text3].Value & "#") <> 0) Then
      MsgBox "Visitor already visited the shop in that particular day"
      Exit Sub
   End If
    
   DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Visitor([Visitor_Name], [Purchase Price], [Date] VALUES ([Text1].Value, [Text2].Value, [Text3].Value)"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much sbgib. 

I have one more question. If I want to check purchase_price also in the condition then how should I need to change the code?

Comment: You're welcome! In the `DCount` function, you would change the 3rd parameter to include it: `If(DCount("Visitor_Name", "Visitor", "Visitor_Name=""" & [Text1].Value & """ AND [Purchase Price]=" & CStr([Text2].Value) & " AND [Date]=#" & [Text3].Value & "#") <> 0) Then`. Think of it as an Access SQL WHERE condition.

Comment: It converts the number to a string. Here's the [reference documentation for CStr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions).

Comment: @ZajjithVedha - The person was kind enough to answer your question and you were kind enough to accept it. Please don't pester them with follow-up questions. If you have a new question [ask it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) separately, adding a link to this question for context, if needed.