# MS Access 2016 - Prevent Duplicate Form Entry

Tags: vba, ms-access, duplicates

[image]Basically I have an Issues table which has a one-to-many relationship with the Service table, that is one particular service can have many issues. The Issues table has in turn a one-to-many relationship with the Breach table. What I want to prevent is the user from entering the same breach against the Issue ID - the Issue can have several different breaches but not the same one. I cannot set the Breach ID properties to 'No Duplicates' as that would prevent the breach being entered against another Issue ID.

This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Breach_ID_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

    If DCount("*", "Breach", "[Issue_ID]= " & Me.[Issue_ID] & " and [Breach_ID]= #") > 0 Then
        MsgBox "You entered a duplicate breach. Please try again.", vbInformation, "Duplicate Breach!"
        Cancel = True
        Me.Breach_ID.Undo
        '...
    End If    

End Sub
```

I am not terribly au fait with VBA and am struggling to get this over the line.

Answer (score 2):

Set `(Issue_ID, Breach_ID)` to be `UNIQUE`, so none of the attributes would be unique by themselves, but together they would be unique.

You will need a composite unique index in order to achieve your goals.

See https://www.geeksengine.com/article/composite-unique-index-access.html

Syntax:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX fk_issue_breach ON Breach (Issue_ID, Breach_ID)
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/create-index-statement-microsoft-access-sql

This will make `(Issue_ID, Breach_ID)` `UNIQUE`, that is, if there are two different records in the table, r1 and r2, then they can match up to one fields of the two, but they cannot duplicate all the fields that part of this composite unique key at the same time.

A `UNIQUE` key is not a `PRIMARY KEY`, even though a `PRIMARY KEY` is unique as well. A `UNIQUE` key is a candidate-key, tha is, it could be a `PRIMARY KEY`, but it so happened that it was not chosen to be a `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: Yes. Here is how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127698/can-we-create-multicolumn-unique-indexes-on-ms-access-databases

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions. However if I cant set Issue ID to unique as it is going to appear more than once, as will the breach ID. Both fields will appear multiple times, but not together. Do you mean that both fields in the table can be set to 'No Duplicates ' but can still appear more than once?

Comment: The suggestion is to create a index on BOTH the ID and breach ID, and thus it will be a combination of both that prevents saving of the record. So, the index will be set as unique, but the index is created on a combination of both columns. the link in above comments shows how you do this.

Comment: Sorry, am not really understanding this and the database doesn't allow me to have 2 primary keys. May just have to leave this as is and write a validation query

Comment: All I was hoping for was some guidance to get this over the line

Comment: Private Sub Breach_ID_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

    If DCount("*", "Breach", "[Issue_ID]= " & Me.[Issue_ID] & " and [Breach_ID]= #") > 0 Then
        MsgBox "You entered a duplicate breach. Please try again.", vbInformation, "Duplicate Breach!"
        Cancel = True
        Me.Breach_ID.Undo
        '...
    End If    

End Sub

Comment: @PaulaMorrison `Issue_ID` is not unique. `Breach_ID` is not unique. `(Issue_ID, Breach_ID)` should be unique, that is, if you have a record whose `Breach_ID` is 5 and `Issue_ID` is 6, then another could have the same `Breach_ID` as well as the same `Issue_ID`, as the corresponding value in this record, **as long as Breach_ID and Issue_ID is not matching at the same time**.