# Creating multiple indexes on an existing table in Microsoft sql

Tags: sql-server

I am converting some sql dump from mysql to run on microsoft sql, but I'm facing an issue with this query:

`ALTER TABLE cms_download_subfolder ADD PRIMARY KEY (folder_id), ADD KEY parent_folder_id (parent_folder_id), ADD KEY client_id (client_id), ADD KEY folder_id (folder_id);`

I get an error on the second Add: `ADD KEY parent_folder_id (parent_folder_id)`.

I understand that in order to add alter a table and add in an index in mssql I would need a `CREATE INDEX` query, however is there a way that I can add multiple indexes to the same table instead of adding one by one?

Comment: Consider looking at this to see if a single multi-column index might help instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179085/multiple-indexes-vs-multi-column-indexes