# What is the difference between single or composite column indexes?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, indexing

In any relational Databases, we can create indexes that boost query speed. But creating more index can damage update/insert speed because the Db system will have to update each index when new data coming (insert, update, merge etc)

We use an example.
we can create a index called index1
ADD INDEX `index1` (`order_id` ASC, `buyer_id` ASC)
OR we can create 2 indexes, index2 and index3
ADD INDEX `index2` (`order_id` ASC)
ADD INDEX `index3` (`buyer_id` ASC)

In a query like this
select * from tablename where order_id>100 and buyer_id>100

Which one is faster? By using Index1 or index2 and index3?

On the other side of the equation, when inserting or updating, I assume it will be much faster to just use one index instead of 2 but I haven't tested it against MySql or MSSQL server so I can't be so sure. If anyone has experience on that matter, do share it please.

And the last thing is about int typed values, I thought it's not possible or relevant to create a index just for int type columns because it doesn't boost the query time, is it true?

Comment: Also note that indexing in Sql Server and MySql are different, so tagging this question with both is problematic as both can have different answers.

Comment: I was intended to link this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179085/multiple-indexes-vs-multi-column-indexes

Comment: My question is more focused on BOTH improving the READ and damaging WRITE efficiency while the other one is more focus on read only operations.

Comment: @vanlightly Although I would agree with you that MySql does have a big difference about using index in a query but in general, I want to answer a more general question. On a general level, creating more indexes will hurt the write speed (update/insert), it's true for both mysql and mssql. And even if it doesn't, I think many people is using mssql and mysql for different projects, they should have a chance to compare and know the difference. At least I do. I don't know if I'm the only one who use both mssql and mysql?

Comment: index2 and index3 -- is optimal for an obtuse reason.  Both of the parts of the `WHERE` are "ranges".  Hence it cannot use both parts of the composite (order_id, buyer_id).  Instead, the optimizer can decide whether `order_id>100` is more selective (and use `INDEX(order_id)`), or the other is better.

Answer (score 0):

For the exact query you mentioned I would personally go for `index1` (you will have a seek operation for both conditions at once). The same index should also do the job even if you filter by `order_id` only (because `order id` is the first column of the index, so the same BTREE structure should still help even if you omit the buyer).

At the same time `index1` would not help much if you filter by `buyer_id` only (because the BTREE will be structured firstly by the missing `order_id` as per the index creation statement). You will probably end up with index scan with `index1`, while having separate indices would still work in that scenario (a seek on `index3` is what should be expected).

Comment: Since both parts are "ranges", a composite index provides no advantage.

Comment: Hmm ... on a second thought I actually tend to agree with what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

The performance of an index are linked to its selectivity, the fact of using two indexes, or a composite index must be assessed, in the context of its application or query particularly critical as regards the performance just by virtue of where on the fields as a possible the index reduces the number of rows to process (and put into joins).

In your case, since an order usually only one buyer is not very selective index order_id, buyer_id (pleasant its usefulness to join operations) as it would be more the reverse, buyer_id, order_id for facilitating the search for orders of a buyer