# Unique Index for firstname and lastname SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, indexing

I've been trying to search for awhile regarding how SQL Server handles unique indexes cause will need to create a table named user the table will have a column first_name and last_name our application will have a search feature which will generally search for first_name or last_name but I'm wondering if I define a unique index with first_name and last_name defined on it if I create a statement like

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_table 
WHERE first_name LIKE 'a%' OR last_name LIKE 'a%';
```

Would this statement still hit the unique index I made for which includes the `first_name` and `last_name`? Or would it be better to define individual indexes for each to optimize the search?

Comment: I think I found the answer from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179085/multiple-indexes-vs-multi-column-indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an index on

```
(first_name, last_name)
```

then this index *might* be used by SQL Server:

- if you use `first_name` **and**  `last_name` in your `WHERE` clause
- if you use `first_name` **only** in your `WHERE` clause
- but **NOT** if you use **only** `last_name` in your `WHERE` clause

The "compound" index can be used if the **N left-most columns** of that index are being used in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that so if it easily hits index so I have to consider columns that might have most number of common values like last_name and next is first_name so I could take advantage of the index in case of searching for particular values where this columns will be included on the where clause.

Comment: I just review your answer and I think I understand it better now the thing is if the arrangement of my unique index goes as first_name, last_name if I search with first_name alone this would definitely use the index in other words in this arrangement if I want the last_name to be indexed as well I also have to declare another index for the last_name alone so that would hit 2 columns one with unique index and one with an individual index which is the last_name even I search alone for any it ensures hitting the index in the absence of any columns in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to optimize the query, then I would recommend writing it as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_table 
WHERE first_name LIKE 'a%' 
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM user_table
WHERE last_name LIKE 'a%' AND first_name NOT LIKE 'a%';
```

This query can take advantage of two indexes on `(last_name)` and `(first_name)` -- you can include more columns in the indexes if you want.

That said, the index will probably not be very selective, so this might not be much improvement on performance.