# Laravel 5.7 + MySQL: Multiple "where" conditions in a query. Index for each "where" column or a single composite index combining all columns?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to improve the performance of my query that's responsible for fetching a stock product from a table. Extremely simple query:

```
select 
    * -- (I know I should not use "*")
from 
    sync_stock_products 
where 
    slug = 'cable-usb-31-type-c-to-a-male-to-male' and 
    dead = 0 and 
    sync_active = 1 
limit 
    1
```

There cannot be a more trivial query, right? Now **each time I fetch a record, I use its unique slug and two boolean flags** (3 `where` conditions). The Product cannot be dead and must be active. I think it's not relevant what above conditions mean.

[image]

Currently, the migration looks like:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('sync_stock_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid(SyncInterface::SYNC_MODEL_PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN_NAME);
        $table->string('stockcode');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->boolean('dead');
        $table->boolean('stkind1');
        (...) heaps of other columns, removed for shorter snippet
        $table->text('field1')->nullable();
        $table->text('smalpic')->nullable();
        $table->text('highrespic')->nullable();
        $table->text('picture4')->nullable();
        $table->text('picture5')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('nonreturn');
        $table->boolean('sync_flag');
        $table->boolean('sync_active');
        $table->timestamp('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
        $table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));

        // Indexes
        $table->primary(SyncInterface::SYNC_MODEL_PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN_NAME);
        $table->unique(SyncInterface::COMPOSITE_KEYS['sync_stock_products']);  
    });
}
```

I already have a primary index on `uuid` (but I don't use `uuid` in the query above). I also define `unique` index on some columns to guarantee composite uniqueness, but this is also irrelevant.

My question is that I want to cover all three columns with index.

Should I put each column in a separate index like:

```
$table->index('slug');
$table->index('dead');
$table->index('sync_active');
```

Or:

```
$table->index(['slug', 'dead', 'sync_active']);
```

[image]

I assume both examples aren't the same? Could someone explain which way is better and would suit this particular case?

Comment: If the `slug` is unique I'd recommend putting a unique index on slug and leaving the other 2 unindexed. Indexing causes inserts/updates to be slower and indexing booleans in case where you also search by an indexed unique column shouldn't add any notable performance

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179085/multiple-indexes-vs-multi-column-indexes) is a pretty good answer

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to index is_active or dead. The cardinality of these columns is very low and it won't help the DB.

Some DB engines allow to include a column in an index which can ave you an extra read but I don't believe MySQL supports that.

You definitely want to index slug if you are querying for it.