# Single-column vs. multi-column index for separate but always together joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, outer-join, database-indexes

If I have a schema like this:

```
profile_network
---
id profile_id(fk) school_type_id(fk) school_major_type_id(fk) school_degree_type_id(fk)
```

And a query that will always be used to join all of those to their respective lookup tables:

```
LEFT JOIN "profile_network" ON "profile_network"."profile_id" = "profile"."id"
LEFT JOIN "profile_network_school_type" ON "profile_network:school_type"."id" = "profile_network"."school_type_id"
LEFT JOIN "profile_network_school_major_type" ON "profile_network:school_major_type"."id" = "profile_network"."school_major_type_id"
LEFT JOIN "profile_network_school_degree_type" ON "profile_network:school_degree_type"."id" = "profile_network"."school_degree_type_id"
```

Should I create 4 indexes on each individual column `(col1)(col2)(col3)(col4)`, or 1 index on all of the columns `(col1, col2, col3, col4)`?

Comment: I would go for the first version.  Do note that if the index is used, it will likely define the ordering of the `JOIN`s.

Comment: Time to read about using indexes. What references said what that is relevant here, including [so]? [ask] A justified answer to this is just rewriting such a reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Indexes vs Multi-Column Indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179085/multiple-indexes-vs-multi-column-indexes)

Comment: I am wondering if indexing for `LEFT JOIN A LEFT JOIN B` acts similarly to indexing for `WHERE A and B`. For `WHERE A and B`, I usually prefer to index separately `(A)(B)` or a concatenated reverse index `(B, A)` instead of `(A, B)` because it wouldn't use the index for `B` alone, but I am not sure if `JOIN`s act similarly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the join type chosen:

- With a nested loop join, an index on the join condition of the lookup tables would help.
- For a hash join, no index helps.
- For a merge join, an index on the join condition of thr lookup table may help.

It all depends on the cardinalities.

A multi-column index is definitely the wrong thing.

Comment: That query with no indexes does hash join. So it sounds like even if I added an index or 4 to it, it's already doing the best it can? I assume this school-related stuff would be considered low to medium cardinality, in this database especially because there are only 10 profile rows. :)

Comment: You'll have to experiment using `EXPLAIN`. That way you can see if an index is used, and you know which join strategy the database uses.