# Compound primary key vs creating a new key that's a function of the primary columns?

Tags: sql

I'm quite new to sql, and I'm working on storing some data where the primary key is made of two columns: a spatial one and a temporal one.

Today, I started wondering instead of having a compound primary key, why not just create a single key that's a function of the 2. This function returns a unique value for a distinct input. I don't know if there's a special term for this procedure in sql.

What are the pros and cons with this approach compared to just having a compound primary key? The latter creates a single spatio-temporal variable, and I feel it's not as intuitive as having 2 variables.

Note that for my application, I don't need ever need to join based on one of the existing 2 primary columns.

Comment: typically a primary key is simply a unique identifier it should not have any meaning other than uniquely identifying your row.

Comment: You can’t have two primary keys on the same table. You could have one PK made up of multiple columns or you can have one PK and multiple unique keys - but not more than one PK

Comment: yes, you can only have  one primary key and what you describe is a combined primay key,

Comment: @NickW sorry, I meant a tuple of 2 columns as the primary key is what I have currently, and my thought is to change it to a single value that's computed based on mapping the 2 colunmns to a single unique value

Comment: It depends. Could you tell us more about this table?

Comment: You're talking about a "Hash". Pros: Tools like Power BI can only join on one column. It can help make some data engineering activities a bit simpler and more automated (i.e .you have 100 tables to replicate and they all have a hashed PK so you use the same algorithm for everything. Cons: You need to calculate it. You need to actually have a use case for this, otherwise I suggest that you don't bother.

Comment: Let me rephrase: are you asking which is better: [Multi-Column Index or Multiple Indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/179085/5045688)? There are many articles on the Internet explaining the pros and cons of both approaches.

Comment: What would be the point, what's wrong with what you have?

Comment: Multi-column compound primary keys can be a major pain when you have a lot of other tables referencing that table using foreign keys. If you want to do this, all the other tables also have to have **ALL** the columns that make up the primary key, in order for foreign key constraints to be built - you *cannot* reference just parts of a compound primary key. All the JOIN operations will get messy, since you have to specify **ALL** columns to be equal between the child and parent table

Comment: **Don't use natural keys, they are never unique**. Currently you are using a "natural key" in the primary key of the table. Natural keys that are values that do have some meaning in the problem being resolved. Just use a synthetic key, and forget about a bunch of issues off the bat.

Comment: @marc_s While I do agree that composite keys are more verbose, there are good use cases when they are the best solution to the problem. I would not avoid them across the board.

Comment: @TheImpaler: an email address is a natural key, is unique and (in many circumstances) makes a great primary key. While I would agree that synthetic keys are the way to go for OLAP solutions (and are, in fact, required for a dimensional model), in OLTP systems having natural keys as the primary key is commonplace

Comment: @NickW "an email address is unique" -- I would disagree. The same goes for SSNs (a couple of mishaps produced thousands of duplicate ones for different people) and phone numbers.

Comment: Not really worth continuing the discussing (as not that relevant to the question) but do you think all those apps and websites where you use your email address to create an account don’t have that email address as a PK?

Answer (score 2):

> why not just create a single key that's a function of the 2

You could do that, but that would be duplicating data. In this case at least the information (probably) won't change, but if it did you'd have to ensure everything remained in sync. Instead, you'd add a simple auto-incrementing integer.

---

In general, there's two types of primary keys. Those which contain row information, and those which are just a unique identifier.

### Unique, meaningless identifier

In general, a unique identifier is simple and safe. This is typically an incrementing integer. [Different databases do it differently](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_autoincrement.asp): "auto_increment" or "serial" or the SQL standard ["identity"](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-identity/). A [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) is another option, basically a random number.

Pros

- Inherently unique and immutable.
- Simple to refer to.
- Leaks no information about the row data (see caveat below)

Cons

- Increases the size of the table by 4, 8, or 16 bytes depending if you use an int, bigint, or uuid.
- Sequential integers leak the order rows were inserted. This can have [real world consequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem).
- If you use an integer, you can run out of IDs.

### Unique data

If you make a multi-column primary key like `primary key(spacial, temporal)`, you're declaring two things:

1. Neither value will ever change.
2. The combination of values is unique.

It's easy to get this wrong. If you do, all references to the row also have to be changed. An example of a poor choice might be `primary key(firstname, lastname)`, because people's names change.

Multi-column primary keys also complicate references. Foreign keys must store both values, making referencing tables larger, and making joins a bit more complicated and expensive.

> Note that for my application, I don't need ever need to join based on one of the existing 2 primary columns.

...for now.

Pros

- Doesn't add to the table size.
- You won't run out of identifiers.

Cons

- A column might not be immutable.
- The primary key might not be unique.
- Foreign keys are larger (along with their indexes).
- The primary key reveals data.

For example, a URL referring to a row would need to contain something like id=123.456,-234.567. This exposes information. In contrast id=54 only exposes that this was probably created after 53 and before 55. id=f63ee603-3e69-4042-92e9-20d6a091edfa (a UUIDv4) reveals nothing, it's just a random 128 bit integer.

### Which one?

If you're new to SQL, the safe thing is to add a unique integer primary key. Its simple and you won't make the mistake of picking a primary key that turns out not to be unique and immutable. You have a succinct way to refer to each row, a simple integer. You won't accidentally leak data.

If space is at a premium, and you don't mind that the primary key revels data, use a multi-column primary key.

For example, let's say you're storing users. You *could* use their username as primary key. It's unique, but if it's the primary key it also has to be immutable; the table design is placing an artificial restriction on the application. Rather than storing an integer, referencing tables must store the whole string which can get large.

Instead, most systems assign an integer user ID in addition to username.

```
create table users (
  id integer primary key generated always as identity,
  name text not null,
  created_at timestamp not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/mBH99JPB).